# Trouble obtaining object values within an array using C#

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using C# and unable to obtain JSON data values for the JSON below:

I am trying to obtain all name value pairs for:

body.quotes.vehicle.key

and

body.quotes.prices.pricing-fixed.price

The JSON contains several of these 'vehicle' and 'prices' objects (repeated for different vehicle types) although I've only included one below to keep the code succinct.

I can see that "quotes" is an array containing multiple vehicle and pricing objects but I'm stuck on the fact that each of the containing objects doesn't seem to have a direct name value pair so I can't work out how to obtain the values I need.

```
{
    "version": 243,
    "code": "0",
    "body": {
        "quotes": [
            {
                "vehicle": {
                    "id": null,
                    "title": "Any Vehicle",
                    "key": "R4",
                    "description": "4 Seater",
                    "group": "NOMAP"
                },
                "prices": {
                    "pricing-fixed": {
                        "id": "18277",
                        "title": "FIXED",
                        "type": "fixedfare",
                        "alt": false,
                        "cost": 25,
                        "price": 25,
                        "tip": 0,
                        "commission": 0.5,
                        "auto": "1",
                        "priority": 1,
                        "schedulable": "1",
                        "for_account": false,
                        "audit": {
                            "zonecharges": []                       
                    },
                    "attributeextras_cost": 0,
                    "attributeextras_price": 0,
                    "round_robin": 0,
                    "waitAndReturn": false,
                    "prebooking_extra_price": "0.00",
                    "waitAndReturnCostDiscount": 0,
                    "waitAndReturnPriceDiscount": 0
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "vehicle": { ...//etc.
```

I have tried the following C# code but `(string)iCabbiVehicleJson["vehicle.key"]` is null. (I believe this line is the problem?)

Code snippet:

```
            string jsonResponseAsString = returnJson.ToString();
            JObject iCabbiResponseJson = JObject.Parse(jsonResponseAsString);

            List<iCabbiQuoteVehicleFare> vehicleFares = new List<iCabbiQuoteVehicleFare>();
            foreach (JToken vehicleFare in iCabbiResponseJson.SelectToken("body.quotes"))
            {
                try
                {
                    JObject iCabbiVehicleJson = JObject.Parse(vehicleFare.ToString());
                    string vehicleKey = (string)iCabbiVehicleJson["vehicle.key"];
                    decimal fare = (decimal)iCabbiVehicleJson["prices.pricing-fixed.price"];
                    vehicleFares.Add(new iCabbiQuoteVehicleFare
                    {
                        VehicleKey = vehicleKey,
                        Fare = fare
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string errorMessage = ex.Message;
                }                        
            }
```

the variable `vehicleFares` actually returns the below. That double curly braces is most likely the issue...

```
{{
  "vehicle": {
    "id": null,
    "title": "Any Vehicle",
    "key": "R4",
    "description": "4 Seater",
    "group": "NOMAP"
  },
  "prices": {
    "pricing-fixed": {
      "id": "18277",
      "title": "FIXED",
      "type": "fixedfare",
      "alt": false,
      "cost": 25,
      "price": 25,
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using recent Visual Studio, you can paste JSON as .net classes

Comment: Many thanks. Yes, I have done this previously but this JSON is obtained from an API call and the supplier that produces this JSON quite often changes the structure I've found iterating over the JSON more stable in this scenario.

Comment: I question that this could ever be made stable if they're constantly changing the json schema

Comment: @DetectivePikachu. Yes. It's caused problems in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the square bracket indexer syntax of `JToken` does not support dotted property paths.  You need to use the `SelectToken()` method for that.

Change these lines:

```
    string vehicleKey = (string)iCabbiVehicleJson["vehicle.key"];
    decimal fare = (decimal)iCabbiVehicleJson["prices.pricing-fixed.price"];
```

to this:

```
    string vehicleKey = (string)iCabbiVehicleJson.SelectToken("vehicle.key");
    decimal fare = (decimal)iCabbiVehicleJson.SelectToken("prices.pricing-fixed.price");
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nkSu5y

Comment: Bingo! Perfect. Thanks for explanation too... I learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just treat them as `dynamic` and iterate over them using a `for` loop. I just did something like this using your example data, and it seemed to work.

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wZWrmD)

```cs
    // Where the data variable holds your json string
    var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(data);
    var count = json.body.quotes.Count;
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine(json.body.quotes[i].vehicle.key);
        Console.WriteLine(json.body.quotes[i].prices["pricing-fixed"]);

    }
```